# How do I make an image overwrite text within another div upon hover of first div?

Tags: javascript, image, html, hover, overwrite

How do I make an image overwrite text within another div upon hover of first div? ? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onload = function () { // ensure that we don't try to get div1 before it's loaded
    document.getElementById("div1").onmouseover = function () {
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "<p>new HTML</p>";
    };
};
```

Depending on your case, you may wish to use the innerText property to ensure that you don't accidentally make HTML, or you can [use the DOM](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml) to make new elements.

Comment: Don't forget the onmouseout event, in case you want it to go back to the original HTML